# SIM800L - GAMMU not connecting - RPI 4

Tags: pi-3, pi-4

I connected my RPI4 & RPI3B one by one with my SIM800L board in hope to be able to receive sms on the board. Unfortunately, the boards do not detect the module. The SIM800l was given external power so that it does not overwhelm the RPI. I connected the GND to the RPI GND, the TX to TX0 and RX to TX0. I have also tried to use ttyS0/ttyAMA0/serial0 to no avail. I tried 2 different GSM boards which both work if interfaced with arduino board but not rpi. I also tried to look using Gammu --identify. But this returns error opening, devices does not exist. I am new to Raspberry pi and i am unable to receive SMS. Please help me out.

Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Hi @akki2402, Welcome. Ah, let me see. My answers/chats to the following SIM800/SIM900 questions might help. (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104479/sim800-gsm-module-to-raspberry-pi-uart-serial-communication-problem
(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104017/sim800-uart-serial-corrupted-response-problem
(3) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/102239/response-to-a-incoming-call-using-python-script
(4) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98523/obtaining-gps-internet-together-with-waveshare-gsm-gprs-gnss-hat-module

Comment: (5) Chat only - https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105301/sim900-a6-gprs-gsm-module-and-rpi4b-uart-communication-problem.  Good luck and cheers.

Comment: BTW, GSM/LTE cards are like GPS modules, sometimes you need a good receiving environment, and a stable externalpower suppy, using a Lipo power bank is sometimes helpful: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98840/rpi-uart-to-gps-module-connection-problem.

Comment: Hi @tlfong01 thank you for the links. but still after following all your advice, i still cant connect...

Comment: There are 101 reasons that you cannot connect: (1) Have you disabled console uart, (2) Have you disabled 1-Wire, (3) Have you tried to use a low speed, say 9,600 baud, (4) Have you disabled the autobaud  config, (5) Have you used any terminal emulators such as Win10 RealTerm, or RpiCuteCom to do loopback, to make sure wiring is OK, (6) Have you tried /dev/USB* instead of /dev/tty*, ... (100) Have you use swap testing, eg, using other RF/433MHz modules such as BlueTooth 4/5 serial module, or RF12B serial modules to do detection tests. Or please tell me if you know how to use a multi-meter, ...

Comment: Or use a Blinky LED program to do hardware troubleshooting, ... Tell us your Arduino project experience, or show us your config/log files, or photos, so that we have a better idea what is going on, ...

Comment: Hi @tlfong01 i had done all these things. I just let my program loop and at one time it just respond. I dont know the cause or reason for that. It just happens to work now. Thank you

Comment: How interesting! Cheers.

Comment: In your post you've written "TX to RX0 and RX to RX0" can you confirm if this is what you have done or if it's a typo? I assume it should be TX->RX and RX-TX?

Comment: @Fred Ahh! it was a typo. Really Sorry. Edited